# Timeout error when using "exists" watir-webdriver method

Tags: ruby, firefox, watir, watir-webdriver

As far as searching goes, i was unable to find an up-to-date list of supported browsers for watir.

I've just upgraded firefox to version 18, and while at it, also update the watir-webdriver version to it's latest (by using `gem update watir-webdriver`).

So far i've encountered one issue, that i cant seem to find a solution for.

When i try to check if an element exist, lets say by using `$browser.a(:href, "#{$url}/admin/").exists?` (The `$url` variable is defined to the main url of my testing server, so it's not the problem. Furthermore, even when i replace the variable with the actual address, i still encounter the same issue), I always get a timeout error when the element does **not** exists.

When the element **does** exists, i will get an instant response of `true`. So the timeout issue only happens when the element does **not** exists.

*So my questions are:*

1. Is there a way to make the `.exists?` method work?
2. Does anyone know any other issues like that with the latest version of Firefox(V. 18)?
3. I would really appreciate if someone can point me to an updated list of watir supported browsers. Preferably a list that is being updated on a regular basis.

P.S,
I did see that someone posted a question about the `present?` method, i have no idea of it's related, but nonetheless, i still have no solution. I'd hate to downgrade to a previous version of ff.

Thanks a bunch to anyone who will be willing to help,

Kind regards,
Asaf.

Comment: What is the exact text of the error you get in the stacktrace?
What is the version of Selenium-webdriver that you have installed?
When you test against a browser other than Firefox does your script throw the same timeout error?

Comment: Actually Abe, You solved the problem for me. i just needed to update the selenium-webdriver gem(which, in my foolishness, i forgot to do) and everything seems to be working as it should. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I had such problems here and there and the solution was to catch the exception and re-run the piece of code that triggered this exception. Of course, I'm assuming your exception is triggered by some transient cause, possibly by a glitch in Watir.

Briefly, you could do something like this:

```
begin
  $browser.a(:href, "#{$url}/admin/").exists?
rescue Timeout::Error
  puts("Caught a TIMEOUT ERROR!")
  sleep(1)
  # Retry the sode that generates the esception.
  retry
end
```

That's the simplest form. You could also make sure not to lock up yourself in an infinite loop by doing something like:

```
retries_left = 3
begin
  $browser.a(:href, "#{$url}/admin/").exists?
rescue Timeout::Error
  puts("Caught a TIMEOUT ERROR!")

  # You may want to wait for a while before retrying.
  sleep(1)

  # Retry the code that generates the exception.
  retries_left -= 1
  retry if retries_left > 0

  # No more retries left - time to bail out! Re-raise the exception.
  raise
end
```

You could improve this a bit by abstracting this exception handling code into a test helper method that accepts blocks and use it in a much more cleaner way, without repeating yourself, like:

```
handle_transient_exceptions {
  $browser.a(:href, "#{$url}/admin/").exists?
}
```

But that's not what you asked about. :)

Referring to your third question, I can say that watir-webdriver supports the latest Chrome, Firefox and IE9 pretty well. I'm working with these browsers currently and haven't spotted any blocking issues yet.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. although im going to take the retries trick with me, sadly it did not fixed the problem. i was looking for a way to avoid changing my code. Upadting the selenium-webdriver gem seemed to fix the problem. Thanks again!